# define different function for different versions of python

Tags: python, multiple-versions

Is there any way to define a different function (with the same body) for different version of python?

specifically, for python 2.7 define:

```
def __unicode__(self):
```

and for python 3 define:

```
def __str__(self):
```

but both will have the same code / body. both must also be a member of class.

Comment: Why not always define both and have them make a call to a third function which contains the actual implementation?

Comment: @deceze because it wouldn't work.

Comment: @deceze: the interface for `__str__` changes between Python 2 and 3. In Python 2, it must return bytes, in Python 3, it must return Unicode.

Comment: @Martijn Then the "adapter" methods `__unicode__` and/or `__str__` could do this simple conversion. That's essentially what the answers do.

Comment: @deceze `__str__` exists in both Python 2 and Python 3, and its return value must be defined differently. Essentially that'd be changing the conditionals that my code executes once per initialization time into once per each invocation, hardly handy anymore.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While there are compatibility libraries; `six` and `future` being the 2 most widely known, sometimes one needs to live without compatibility libs. You can always write your own class decorator, and put it into say `mypackage/compat.py`. The following works nicely for writing the class in Python 3 format and converting the 3-ready class to Python 2 if needed (the same can be used for `next` vs `__next__`, etc:

```
import sys

if sys.version_info[0] < 3:
    def py2_compat(cls):
        if hasattr(cls, '__str__'):
            cls.__unicode__ = cls.__str__
            del cls.__str__
            # or optionally supply an str that 
            # encodes the output of cls.__unicode__
        return cls
else:
    def py2_compat(cls):
        return cls

@py2_compat
class MyPython3Class(object):
    def __str__(self):
        return u'Here I am!'
```

(notice that we are using u'' prefix which is PyPy 3, and Python 3.3+ compatible only, so if you need to be compatible with Python 3.2, then you need to adjust accordingly)

---

To supply a `__str__` method that encodes the `__unicode__` to UTF-8 in Python 2, you can replace the `del cls.__str__` with

```
def __str__(self):
    return unicode(self).encode('UTF-8')
cls.__str__ = __str__
```

Answer (score 4):

The third-party `six` library defines a [`python_2_unicode_compatible`](https://pythonhosted.org/six/#six.python_2_unicode_compatible) class decorator which takes a class with a `__str__` method and translates it to `__unicode__` on Python 2.